# ^^M garbles my terminal output

Tags: luatex, terminal-output

Contrarily to pdfTeX and XeTeX, which send `^^M` to the terminal for the character `13`, LuaTeX sends the character `13` itself.  This garbles the output of my terminal (bash under Ubuntu 10.04).

```
\edef\foo{\string\^^M}
\message{\meaning\foo ab}
```

gives

```
abcro:->\
```

i.e., the same as

```
macro:->\
ab
```

but smashed into a single line.  How can I tell LuaTeX to output `^^M` instead?

Comment: This seems like a bug.

Comment: @egreg I had started to submit a bug report, but then had doubts on whether it was a bug or simply that I should change how `^^M` was displayed in my particular terminal. I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: Bug report submitted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @egreg says, it looks like a bug to me. For writing to files you can modify a lua callback but unfortunately the callback (as documented) is not called when writing to the terminal.

```
\edef\foo{\string\^^M}

{\catcode`\^=12
\directlua{
callback.register(
"process_output_buffer",
function  (s)
snew, n =  string.gsub(s,"\string\r","^^M")
return snew
end)
}}


\message{\meaning\foo ab}
\newwrite\x
\immediate\openout\x=nnl.out
\immediate\write\x{\meaning\foo ab}

\stop
```

On the terminal you get

```
ab )o:->\
```

but in the file you get:

```
$ cat nnl.out
macro:->\^^Mab
```

Comment: I'll submit a bug report.

Answer (score 12):

From **LuaTeX Reference, beta 0.70.1**, section **2.3 UNICODE text support**:

> Output to the terminal uses `^^` notation for the lower control range (c < 32),
>   with the exception of `^^I`, `^^J` and `^^M`. These are considered 'safe' and
>   therefore print-as-is.

And in the manual are the terminal/log explicitely excluded for
`process_output_buffer`:

> 4.1.3.2 `process_output_buffer` (0.43)
>   […]
>   It is only called for output to an actual file (that is, excluding the log,
>   the terminal, and `\write18` calls).

Comment: Ah, so that is not a bug, rather a bad feature.  However, it leads to a garbled terminal output, so a work-around would be useful.  Do you agree with David that there is no appropriate callback for this?

Comment: Not really, the output of the terminal/log is messed up anyway
with much loss of information (catcodes, line breaks, &hellip;).
If you are debugging such stuff, then you can use a decent editor
&mdash; the data are not lost, even `less` shows me the `^^M` as
control character. Not having a callback has its advantages.
The user knows, nobody has messed up with the output, showing
beautiful things while doing malicious things.